# Rails does not work on Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-lion, rvm

I changed my Mac OSX version to Lion. However I cannot create a Rails3 app.

I use rvm 1.9.2 and i choose ruby 1.9.2-p290 to create Rails 3 app.

Everything seems okey. When I start to create a new app

```
rails new new_my_app
```

I see this errors,

```
Installing json (1.6.6) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try

```
gem install json -v '1.6.6'
```

I face this errors

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install "Command Line Tools" from preferences in Xcode 4 for Lion.

Comment: This and this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027772/failed-to-build-json-1-6-3-with-native-extension-after-i-installed-xcode-4-2

Finally made my bundle work again!

Comment: This linked worked for me on a fresh osx mountain lion install that was giving me this error.

Comment: Same as @Catfish. Thought command line tools came over with my Time Machine restored OS on a new SSD. It did not. Solved, thanks!

Comment: Also, be sure to restart after installing the command line tools. Hope it saves someone else some pain

Answer (score 1):

You need to install osx-gcc-installer

If you migrated ruby from previoys system you need to reinstall ruby and gems:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.2
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset pristine
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and this fixed it for me. I recently migrated from an older system to a new iMac.

I first installed libksba. I'm not sure if it's necessary, but I guess it doesn't hurt. I use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) so this is what I did:

```
brew install libksba
```

Then, I updated rvm.

```
rvm get head
```

After updating, it informed me that I needed to install ruby-1.9.3-p194.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

That got 1.9.3 installed. I wanted 1.9.2 for some older apps so I then reinstalled that.

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.2
```

Finally, I installed the json gem that was causing this issue:

```
gem install json -v '1.6.6'
```

Viola! It installed correctly. The last thing I did was to run bundle, but it was complaining about not finding this:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.3.1 in any of the sources
```

I removed Gemfile.lock and re-ran bundle.

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle
```

And everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I won it. Maybe it could be the short or easy way. You know.
Firstly, I updated the RVM but before it, i installed Xcode 4 from appstore for Lion. The second step is the reinstall the lastest stabil ruby version and create my gemset. 
And finally I download the rails 3.2 to the gem set which i set before on ruby the lastest.